# Transparent soil, regular soil and hydroponics

Tags: soil, hydroponic

1. Does any kind, of any kind grow hydroponic?
2. What is your opinion about the plant grow on Hydroponics?
3. Can I move the plants I have on regular soil to Hydroponics safely?
4. What's your opinion about polyvinyl alcohol granules?

**Kind regards;
Chris**

Comment: You need to ask 4 separate questions, and expand on them as many are unclear as to meaning.

Comment: use grammar, and try to be as specific as you can when asking a question, and don't ask opinion questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is many questions in one and they need more work. Please see the [help] for details.

Comment: @blackthumb That comment should have started with a capital U. With all due respect, when you advise someone to use grammar, starting the sentence with the proper punctuation is a good idea. :)

Comment: @Sue it was more of a statement than a question

Comment: Hi Chris Russo! I see you've been around the network for a few years, so welcome and thanks for joining us. Of course you're free to edit this, or especially split it into more than one question, while it's on hold. It might help you to look through some of our other questions with the [tag:hydroponic] tag. You might get some answers for at least parts of this question, or check out some ways that people are asking those types of questions. Please leave us a note if you need further clarification. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies for any mistake done publishing here, I'm a programmer from SO, biology and plants are my hobbie. I'll try to ask separated questions in the next cases, but I was looking for a general opinion about the matter. Someone gave a general a good answer in any case! I'm following him. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer a few of your questions and definitely give you my opinions, grins!

NO you should not take plants grown in soil and grow them further hydroponically.  Roots grown in soil are different than roots grown in water.  Sort of like starting an Avocado seed in water then transferring it to soil.  Yes, it can be done but one avocado seed is easier than a whole garden of plants grown in soil then put in water.

My opinion on hydroponics.  People say that plants grow faster and better, etc. I believe them. I know how to grow plants in soil.  Not hydroponically.  I like knowing I am doing the au natural thing plants understand and need.  I am a frickin' expert and I see hydroponics as mind numbing technology to grow plants in an unnatural way. This assumes we humans know plants well enough to recreate what they need, what their genetics expect and demand without once making a mistake.  On that subject, I KNOW us humans have a long ways to go to be able to KNOW plants and their needs.

One mistake the whole mess is a done deal and have to start over.  I love knowing that one mistake growing in soil won't kill the entire kit and kaboodle.  One plant in trouble gives me an indicator to save the rest.  Beginners such asI am assuming you are should stick with learning how to grow in soil before ever attempting to grow in OTHER than soil. I have used the artificial grow mediums and hated them.  There will be other answers from those who swear by hydroponics and have used hydroponics but I'll bet they all started with soil based first.  I don't see ever using hydroponics in my future.  I am of the club that humans are just stupid and arrogant, grins, to think we know how to grow plants better that the way they were designed.  Hey, hydroponics is a big deal and successful as well, but I haven't been impressed.  Growing hydroponically is a good 'stretch' for experienced gardeners but a disaster for newbies.  That is my opinion.

Polyvinyl crystals I've seen used in soil are flat out dumb.  Automatic irrigation is better.  Best is manual watering that allows one to visually and tactically know what your plants need...if we don't understand how to grow plants in soil why the heck would we try to grow hydroponically?

If you have become proficient with growing in soil then it shall be a good experiment to grow hydroponically.  I give you my blessing and admiration.  I've read tons on this subject yet I am just not convinced enough to make a system that is completely reliant on mesef.  Good ole soil I understand.  And still the responsibility is huge.

Dealing with people (the bulk of our populations) who know nothing about plants, includes the idea that plants are like animals. For example; MOST people actually think fertilizer is food.  All the weird yummy sounding fish fertilizers, coffee grounds and other additives are mostly to assuage guilt and ignorance of plants.  Plants make their own food.  We are relegated to supply the chemicals we've stripped from our soils, to make subsoils into topsoils with the addition of decomposed organic matter and SMALL additions of macro NPK chemicals and micro chemicals (Boron, magnesium, molybdenum, sulfur, iron, calcium and MORE)  I say CHEMICALS instead of nutrients because dog gone it, people think of these chemicals as food.  And us humans think food is good.  The more the better.  Which is totally NOT TRUE and usually fatal with plants...sigh.

If you know how to grow plants in soil then have at it with hydroponics!!  If you understand the scientific language you'll be able to get a great start via the internet.  I am just saying, if you aren't prolific with plants in soil, you should start there first.  Become very knowledgeable with soil and plants.  You asked for opinions and that is mine.

Comment: I think it's common to take starts grown in soil, wash the soil off. And then grow them out hydroponically.

Comment: Thanks, @GrahamChiu.  You know how roots grown in water are different than roots grown for soil.  Can be done but I would think it would be similar the other way taking soil roots and making them water roots.  Doable but I wouldn't think great for commercial, which is most hydroponically grown crops...sounds stressful to a plant.  I don't know much about hydroponics.  Mostly because knowing what it takes to grow a plant normally is in itself STILL overwhelming.  To imagine having to grow plants in a foreign medium, relying on technological stuff reduces my interest but with all these questions

Comment: Roots are never grown in water, they're grown in grow media (rockwool, coir, etc.), of which soil can be a perfectly acceptable medium.  You have to be careful not to introduce diseases into your system if you use soil, but if you're using isolated DWC buckets or similar you won't spread any problems you might have.

Comment: There are different roots made by the same plant for different mediums.  Roots for water are not the roots that plant would exhibit for soil.  Hydroponics is different than growing in soil.  Hydroponics needs water roots.  It is possible to plant a hydroponic plant into soil, carefully.  Always potting soil before the garden soil, however. Sterilized potting soil, rockwool (ick), coir...never use garden soil.